# Creating a list of particle positions for each gridcell

Tags: python, density-plot

I am creating a charge smear function. I have a matrix were each row is a particle with a charge and position. I then look at each particles position in a grid, to count how many particles are in each grid-cell, but I need to know which cell each particle is in, so that I may find the average of the positions for every particle in a specific grid-cell. My idea for a fix is to create an list where the number of rows is the amount of grid-cells in my matrix, and let the column be positions in x,y and z direction, but obviously I can't append more then one number to each index, but maybe some variation will work? Sorry for open ended question. Thank you in advance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import numpy as np


###Initalize particle lists 
particle_arrayX=[]
particle_arrayY=[]


###The resolution
N = 10

###Number of particles
M = 1000
col=None
row=None
###Size of box
Box_size=100
###gridsize
Grid_size=Box_size/N

###Initalize particles
for i in range(M):
    particle_arrayX.append(random.random()*Box_size)
    particle_arrayY.append(random.random()*Box_size)
    
###Intialize matrix
ParticleMatrix_Inital=[[0 for i in range(N)]]*N


###Measure density in each cell
for i in range(M):
    
    col=None
    row=None
    #The x and y components are diveded by the gridsize
    #Then they are converted to integers and then asigned either to a row or column
    #If value is float with decimal 0 EX 2.0, then 1 is substracted before converted to int
    coln=particle_arrayX[i]/Grid_size
    rown=particle_arrayY[i]/Grid_size
    
    if coln.is_integer()==True:
        col=int(coln)-1
    else:
        col=int(coln)
    if rown.is_integer()==True:
        row=int(rown)-1
    else:
        row=int(rown)
    ParticleMatrix_Inital=np.array(ParticleMatrix_Inital)
    
    ParticleMatrix_Inital[row,col]=ParticleMatrix_Inital[row,col]+1
    ParticleMatrix_Inital=ParticleMatrix_Inital.tolist()

#Plot matrix
plt.imshow(ParticleMatrix_Inital)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

There are many ways to approach the problem of "bin-ing" empirical data. I'm proposing an object oriented (OO) solution below, because (in my subjective opinion) it provides clean, tidy and highly readable code. On the other hand, OO-solutions might not be the most efficient if you're simulating huge many-particles systems. If the below code doesn't entirely solve your issues, I still hope that parts of it can be of some help to you.

That being said, I propose implementing your grid as a `class`. To make life easier for our self, we may apply the *convention* that all particles have positive coordinates. That is `x`, `y` and even `z` (if introduced) stretches from `0` to whatever `box_size` you define. However, the `class Grid` does not really care about the actual `box_size`, only the resolution of the grid!

```py
class Grid:
    def __init__(self, _delta_x, _delta_y):
        self.delta_x = _delta_x
        self.delta_y = _delta_y
    def bounding_cell(self, x, y):
        # Note that y-coordinates corresponds to matrix rows,
        # and that x-coordinates corresponds to matrix columns
        return (int(y/self.delta_y), int(x/self.delta_x))
```

**Yes**, this could have been a simple function. However, as a class it is easily expandable. Also, a function would have rely on global variables (yuck!) or explicitly be given the grid spanning (`delta`) in each dimensional direction, for every determining of which matrix cell (or bin) the given coordinate `(x,y)` belongs to.

Now, how does it work? Imagine the simplest of cases, where your grid resolution is `1`. Then, a particle at position `(x,y) = (1.2, 4,9)` should be placed in the matrix at `(row,col) = (4,1)`. That is `row = int(y/delta_y)` and likewise for `x`. The higher resolution (smaller `delta`) you have, the larger the matrix gets in terms of number of rows and cols.

Now that we have a `Grid`, let us also object orient the Particle! Rather straight forward:

```py
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, _id, _charge, _pos_x, _pos_y):
        self.id = _id
        self.charge = _charge
        self.pos_x = _pos_x
        self.pos_y = _pos_y
    def __str__(self):
        # implementing the __str__ method let's us 'print(a_particle)'
        return "{%d, %d, %3.1f, %3.1f}" % (self.id, self.charge, self.pos_x, self.pos_y)
    def get_position(self):
        return self.pos_x, self.pos_y
    def get_charge(self):
        return self.charge
```

This class is more or less just a collection of data, and could easily have been replaced by a dict. However, the class screams its intent clearly, it is clean and tidy, and also easily expanded.

Now, let's create some instances of particles! Here is a function which by list comprehension creates a list of particles with an `id`, `charge` and position `(x,y)`:

```py
import random
def create_n_particles(n_particles, max_pos):
    return [Particle(id, # unique ID
                     random.randint(-1,1), # charge [-1, 0, 1]
                     random.random()*max_pos, # x coord
                     random.random()*max_pos) # y coord
            for id in range(n_particles)]
```

And finally, we get to the fun part: putting it all together:

```py
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    n_particles = 1000
    box_size = 100
    grid_resolution = 10
    grid_size = int(box_size / grid_resolution)

    grid = Grid(grid_resolution, grid_resolution)

    particles = create_n_particles(n_particles, box_size)

    charge_matrix = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size))

    id_matrix = [[ [] for i in range(grid_size)] for j in range(grid_size)]

    for particle in particles:
        x, y = particle.get_position()
        row, col = grid.bounding_cell(x, y)
        charge_matrix[row][col] += particle.get_charge()
        # The ID-matrix is similar to the charge-matrix,
        # but every cell contains a new list of particle IDs
        id_matrix[row][col].append(particle.id)
```

Notice the initialization of the ID-matrix: This is the **list of particle positions for each grid cell** that you asked for. It is a matrix, representing the particle container, and each cell contains a list to be filled with particle IDs. You could also populate these lists with entire particle instances (not just their IDs): `id_matrix[row][col].append(particle)`.

The last `for` loop does the real work, and here the Object Oriented strategy shows us how charming it is: The loop is short and it is very easy to read and understand what is going on: A cell in the `charge_matrix` contains the total charge within this grid cell/bin. Meanwhile, the `id_matrix` is filled with the IDs of the particles that is contained within this grid cell/bin.

From the way we've constructed the list of particles, `particles`, we see that a particle's ID is equivalent to that particle's index in the list. Hence, they may be retrieved like this,

```py
for i,row in enumerate(id_matrix):
    for j,col in enumerate(row):
        print("[%d][%d] : " % (i, j), end="")
        for particle_id in id_matrix[i][j]:
            p = particles[particle_id]
            # do some work with 'p', or just print it:
            print(p, end=", ")
        print("") # print new line


# Output:
# [0][0] : {32, -1, 0.2, 0.4}, ... <-- all data of that particle
# ....
```

I leave optimization of this retrieval to you as I don't really know what data you need and what you're going to do with it. Maybe it's better to contain all the particles in a dict instead of a list; I don't know(?). You choose!

At the very end, I'll suggest that you use `matshow` which is inteded for displaying matrices, as opposed to `imshow` which is more aiming more for images.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(charge_matrix)
fig.colorbar(cax)
ax.invert_yaxis() # flip the matrix such that the y-axis points upwards
fig.savefig("charge_matrix.png")
```

[image]

We can also scatter plot the particles and add grid lines corresponding to our the grid in the `matshow` above. We color the scatter plots such that negative charges are blue, neutral are gray and positive are red.

```py
def charge_color(charge):
    if charge > 0: return 'red'
    elif charge < 0: return 'blue'
    else: return 'gray'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 101, grid_resolution))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 101, grid_resolution))
ax.grid()
ax.scatter([p.pos_x for p in particles],
            [p.pos_y for p in particles],
            c=[charge_color(p.get_charge()) for p in particles])
fig.savefig("particle_dist.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
It might not be the best solution to create a physical grid, since eventually I want to simulate 1.000.000 particles or more, but in any case your comment has made my gears turning towards solutions that were more applicable to my specific data.

Comment: @JaZper_0099 Can you please eloborate on what you mean by "physical grid"?

Comment: ... the Grid as implemented here is very well suited for many-particle systems. The `class Particle`, maybe not so much. However, from initialization to completing the work loop  of 1 million particles takes about 22 seconds on my system.. Which I would say is quite decent for Python.